# Steps to integrate Swift Framework into Objective C Project?

Tags: objective-c, swift, objc-bridging-header

I have an Objective C Project and I need a scrollable tab. So I came cross the below framework [scrollableTab](https://github.com/cemolcay/SlidingContainerViewController)

Its a swift framework and I added it using cocoa pods.

I could add @import SlidingContainerViewController;
but I was not able to access some properties like

```
slidingContainerViewController.sliderView.appearance.outerPadding = 0;
slidingContainerViewController.sliderView.appearance.innerPadding = 50;
slidingContainerViewController.sliderView.appearance.fixedWidth = true;
slidingContainerViewController.delegate = self;
```

These properties are inside another swift file SlidingContainerSliderView.swift.

Please suggest any other solution.

I also have issue with [PageMenu](https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu) which is a Swift Framework. I am adding it to my Objective C Project.

@import PageMenu;
@property (nonatomic) CAPSPageMenu *pagemenu;

works without errors but cannot load anything and following is throwing error: Use of undeclared identifier 'CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemSeparatorWidth', 'CAPSPageMenuOptionUseMenuLikeSegmentedControl','CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemSeparatorPercentageHeight'

which is public enum CAPSPageMenuOption {
    case selectionIndicatorHeight(CGFloat)
    case menuItemSeparatorWidth(CGFloat)
} in CAPSPageMenu+Options.swift file

```
// Customize page menu to your liking (optional) or use default   settings by sending nil for 'options' in the init
// Example:
NSDictionary *parameters = @{CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemSeparatorWidth: @(4.3),
                             CAPSPageMenuOptionUseMenuLikeSegmentedControl: @(YES),
                             CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemSeparatorPercentageHeight: @(0.1)
                             };
```

Comment: You need to change code like slidingContainerViewController.appearance.outerPadding = 0;

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya sorry I tried but it shows error so self.slidingContainerViewController.sliderView.appearance is correct. the issue is with accessing properties like outerPadding, innerPadding, fixedWidth which are public struct SlidingContainerSliderViewAppearance {
  public var outerPadding: CGFloat
  public var innerPadding: CGFloat
  public var fixedWidth: Bool
} in slidingContainerSliderView.Swift file